# "The only one fooled" vs "the only one being fooled"

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between the two? Is one of the ungrammatical? Example:

> At first I thought he was the victim. Then I realized that, no, **the
>   only one  fooled** was me.
>
> At first I thought he was the victim. Then I realized that, no, **the
>   only one being fooled** was me.

Comment: What is your reason/thinking for adding "being"? More context and an idea of the timeframe are really needed to decide.

Answer (score 6):

Neither of them is ungrammatical. It just depends on what the situation is.

> At first I thought he was the victim. Then I realized that, no, the **only one fooled** was me.

This sentence means that this has happened in the past.

> At first I thought he was the victim. Then I realized that, no, the **only one being fooled** was me.

["Being"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/being) indicates the situation is still happening right now. (Definition of "being": the fact of existing)